# MSSQL function to convert string to valid JSON

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql

I would like to create a MSSQL scalar function to convert a string to valid JSON. As far as I can tell newline, returns and quote characters are an issue but I cannot find a complete list or a complete function.

This is what I have so far:

```
Create Function [dbo].[StringToJSON] 
(@MyString as varchar(Max))
Returns varchar(Max)
As
Begin
    --NULL
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(0),' ');
    --Horizontal Tab
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(9),' ');
    --Line Feed
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(10),'\n');
    --Vertical Tab
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(11),' ');
    --Form Feed
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(12),'\n');
    --Carriage Return
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(13),'\n');
    --Column Break
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(14),' ');
    --Non-breaking space
    Set @MyString = Replace(@MyString,CHAR(160),'');

    Set @MyString = LTRIM(RTRIM(@MyString));
    Return @MyString
End
Go
```

Comment: This link mentions other characters : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921889.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Whats really interesting in that link is the built in support for outputting JSON in SQL Server 2016 - too bad its not in earlier versions

Comment: If you think the question can be marked as answered, you can mark the answer as valid, I just posted my earlier comment as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link mentions other characters :

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921889.aspx](http://This%20link%20mentions%20other%20characters%20:%20msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921889.aspx%20%E2%80%93)